# Failed to open the Group Policy Object. You may not have appropriate rights

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2003-r2

[**I have installed windows 2003 server but unable to create AD (Active directory) I am facing this error.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go042.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure an admin user with valid permissions level is running the installation and this is a stand alone server, then look and analyze the file contents in the Registry.pol file that is most probably located in the "%Systemroot%\System32\GroupPolicy". I think you can backup/remove those contents and try again after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 domaincontrollers, compare the 2 SYSVOL folders on both the DC's to make sure that they are identical.

Usually that error is due to the SYSVOL folders not being the exactly the same, or permission problems on the SYSVOL folder on the DC that won't let you change the GP's. 
Typically one of the two above is the problem.
Probably permissions on the SYSVOL folder on the DC that wont let you edit the GP's

Found this on [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/350947-can-t-edit-new-gp-objects-in-ad-2003-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)